# Show that if $|N|$ and $|H|$ are relatively coprime , then all complements to $N$ in $G$ are conjugate.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

My homework requires me to prove the following results without referring to the Schur-Zassenhaus theorem:

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group such that $G=N\rtimes H$, where $H$ is abelian. Show that if $|N|$ and $|H|$ are relatively coprime , then all complements to $N$ in $G$ are conjugate.

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group such that $G=N\rtimes H$, where $H$ is nilpotent. Show that if $|N|$ and $|H|$ are relatively coprime , then all complements to $N$ in $G$ are conjugate.

Actually I've read the complete proof of Schur-Zassenhaus theorem, but I think there should be some simpler way (instead of reproving the S-Z theorem) to solve the problems above exploiting the special structure of $H$. I have given it lots of thought but nothing works. Can someone help me?

Comment: I presume that you are allowed to use Sylow's theorem. You can do this by repeated use of the conjugation part of Sylow's theorem to the Sylow subgroups of $H$. To start it off, let $H_1$ and $H_2$ be two complements, let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be Sylow $p$-subgroups of $H_1$ and $H_2$ for some prime $p$. Then by conjugating $P_2$ to $P_1$ you can assume that $P_1=P_2$, and since $P_1$ is normal in $H_1$, you can assume that $P_1 \unlhd G$.

Comment: Yes I can use Sylow's theorem . But why exactly can I assume that $P_1$ is normal in $G$?

Comment: Oh I see what you meant! Thank you!